# what's the jquery plugin that inserts text in a textbox, and it disappears upon focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

what's the jquery plugin that inserts text in a textbox, and it disappears upon focus?

Answer (score 4):

the [watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) one?

edit to add another, there are a few watermark plugins, [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/updnWatermark) one is from the jquery pages

Comment: yeah I think this is the one, I believe twitter uses this one.

Comment: not wanting to seem grabby but, could you accept the answer then :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of those plugins, and they all have different names. I programmed one called [InField Labels](http://fuelyourcoding.com/in-field-labels/), and it has been improved by Trevor Davis. [His post](http://www.viget.com/inspire/a-better-jquery-in-field-label-plugin/) actually walks through a lot of back story that is important to your decision.

Another good one is [Labelify](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/labelify/).

Answer (score 1):

[ClearField](http://labs.thesedays.com/projects/jquery/clearfield/)